# How do you parse a number like "1.8400e-016" from a text file in Java?

Tags: java, parsing

I was thinking about putting the first values given at the top as constants, and the rest of the data in a 2D array list. However, what would be a more efficient way to parse this data in Java. Also, how do would you read a number like "1.8400e-016" ? 
In addition, would nextInt only catch the integer in nextLine? 
Sorry Im not familiar with IO in java.

Thanks in advance,

Text File Example:

```
Resistance per unit length (ohm/um): 0.0165
Capacitance per unit length (F/um): 1.8400e-016
Sink node capacitance (F): 2.500000e-016
Buffer output resistance (ohm): 0.01
Sinkcount: 267
Nodecount: 965

%thisnode  parnode  lcnode  rcnode  length(um)  xloc(um)  yloc(um)

1 534 -1 -1 405.080000 29322.000000 41420.000000
2 535 -1 -1 1635.360000 26208.000000 51579.000000
3 536 -1 -1 561.000000 35565.000000 61661.000000
4 537 -1 -1 223.150000 36852.000000 64281.000000
5 538 -1 -1 648.000000 33416.000000 62525.000000
6 539 -1 -1 1828.300000 36915.000000 67124.000000
7 270 -1 -1 126.700000 32275.000000 58078.000000
8 327 -1 -1 1358.200000 30591.000000 67258.000000
9 540 -1 -1 648.000000 33180.000000 61229.000000
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are using the `java.util.Scanner` class to read the numbers? Don't use `nextInt`, but rather `nextDouble`.

Comment: Also if you are asking about parsing a file, you should show some code because there are many ways to parse a file

Comment: Or, more generally, call `Double.parseDouble()`.

Comment: Yes. Will this have any issues with integers? i supposed not, since the memory required by an integer is less than that of a double, so no there;s no loss in precision. However, there's both, integers and doubles in the file, would nextDouble catch both?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `java.util.Scanner` class. The scanner has a `hasNextDouble()` function to check if the next token in your file is a double value. Then you can obtain the value with `nextDouble()`. The scanner also allows you to read you table data easily. You can just use a loop and read the ints with `nextInt()` and text cells with `next()`.

Here an example for your data table, not the text in front. You would need to set the array size large enough or use something like a `List`.

```java
Locale.setDefault(Locale.ROOT);
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
List<Double> l = new ArrayList<>();
int[] thisnode = new int[10];
int[] parnode = new int[10];
int[] lcnode = new int[10];
int[] rcnode = new int[10];
double[] Length = new double[10];
double[] xloc = new double[10];
double[] yloc = new double[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10 && sc.hasNextInt(); i++) {
    thisnode[i] = sc.nextInt();
    parnode[i] = sc.nextInt();
    lcnode[i] = sc.nextInt();
    rcnode[i] = sc.nextInt();
    Length[i] = sc.nextDouble();
    xloc[i] = sc.nextDouble();
    yloc[i] = sc.nextDouble();
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(thisnode));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parnode));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lcnode));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rcnode));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Length));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xloc));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(yloc));
```

Which produces

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
[534, 535, 536, 537, 538, 539, 270, 327, 540, 0]
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0]
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0]
[405.08, 1635.36, 561.0, 223.15, 648.0, 1828.3, 126.7, 1358.2, 648.0, 0.0]
[29322.0, 26208.0, 35565.0, 36852.0, 33416.0, 36915.0, 32275.0, 30591.0, 33180.0, 0.0]
[41420.0, 51579.0, 61661.0, 64281.0, 62525.0, 67124.0, 58078.0, 67258.0, 61229.0, 0.0]
```

The line where i set the locale is only used to prevent the scanner from using the localized number format. My default locale is German and therefore the scanner expects that the decimal numbers use a `,` to separate the decimal places instead of a `.`. If this works for you you don't need to use this line.

The `nextDouble()` function will deal just fine with your `1.8400e-016` if this number is in the normal scientific format with decimal exponent.

Comment: A couple of questions:

1) What is locale.setDefault(locale.ROOT) for?
2) How would you deal with an entry such as: "1.8400e-016" ?
3) How are you parsing thisnode before parnode? seems to me you are just catching the same int at once.

Comment: I've updated the answer for the first two questions. For the last one: It looks fine to me. Look at the first two lines of the output. The numbers are separated into two arrays or am I missing something?